# Can't Install More RAM

Tags: memory, ddr3, dual-channel

I have four RAM slots on my motherboard. I'm currently using two. For some reason, when I plug in a third (and fourth), I can only use the new RAM, and not all of it combined. It's a "dual channel" motherboard, and admittedly, I don't know what that means.

So this is probably a really n00b question, but does anyone know why I can't use every slot at the same time? And if I can't use every slot, why even include extra slots?

Thanks.

Update: Here's all the technical specs I know...

I'm running Windows 8 Pro 64-bit (RTM). I'm using DDR3 RAM, but I'm not sure what clock speed or whatever. I have two 4 GB sticks currently installed, and I'm trying to install two more 4 GB sticks, to bring the total to 16 GB. My motherboard has four RAM slots, and it supports "dual channel" RAM, although I'm not 100% sure what that means. Hopefully that's enough information to go on.

Comment: Need more detail! Please edit your question to include the type and capacity of the RAM chips you're using and the model number of your motherboard.

Comment: Are you using a 32 or 64 bit operating system?

Comment: You need to know the clock speeds of the RAM. Install the initial RAM, run a program like CPUID or Speccy to determine the clock speed. Remove, install second RAM set. Use same program(s) again, post results here.

Comment: what motherboard?

Comment: ASUS P7P55 LX Motherboard

Comment: Check the `Memory Configurations` section of your motherboard manual. Download it [here](http://support.asus.com/download.aspx?m=P7P55+LX&os=30) if you don't happen to have a printed copy. All installed memory modules must have the same CAS latency.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?